# Python III generator that iterates through all possible combinations 32 bytes of data, can there be a faster way?

Tags: python, iterator, hex, byte, generator

How can I make this Python III code more efficient? I am trying to iterate through all possible combinations of 32 bytes, this script is done in hexadecimal, I am open to any data type possibilities. I can't seem to find a faster way than to use a generator and then convert the integers to_bytes(32, 'big').

The output will be sent to a hashlib.new("sha256") function. I can't seem to find a way to do this with just bytes and not conversion, as I need to brute-force every possible combination. Do you see any problems with my concept or something I have missed?

Thank you for any help you can send.

```
import hashlib

import binascii

strike_counter = 0

def hex_permutations(digits=16):

    x = 0

    max_ = 16 ** digits

    while x < max_:

        yield x.to_bytes(32, 'big') # might be little endian

        x += 1

for permutations in hex_permutations(4): # change the number here for more.

    strike_counter += 1

    #print("strike_counter: ", strike_counter, permutations)

    print("strike counter: ", strike_counter)

else:

    print("strike counter: ", strike_counter, permutations)

    pr = binascii.hexlify(permutations)

    print("permutations hexlify: ", pr)

    print("length: ", len(pr))
```

output:

```sh
strike counter:  65536 

b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff'

permutations hexlify:  b'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffff'

length:  64
```

Comment: You are trying to generate (2**8)**32 = 115 792 089 237 316 195 423 570 985 008 687 907 853 269 984 665 640 564 039 457 584 007 913 129 639 936 possibilities which is stupidly big. Even all the computers of the world together (including supercomputers) working for centuries will not be able reach 0.0001% of all the possibilities with a super optimized native code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs more to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) community, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard why is it raised to the power of 32? Wouldn't it be 2^8×32 = 8192 possibilities?

Comment: @NathanJones `(2**8)**32` is equal to `2**(8*32)` and to `2**256` but not to `(2**8)*32`. The number of values in a n-bit number is 2**n. For example, it is `2**32` ~= 4e9 for a 32-bit unsigned integer. ~2e9 for a 64-bit integer. And it is the above number for a 256-bit integer (sha-256 generates 256-bit integers). Put it shortly adding 1 bit double the number of values. Thus adding n bits multiply the number of values by `2**n`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for explaining, that makes sense.